# What is the best format for using SIFT?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

Is there any difference in terms of precision and speed in using SIFT with JPEG, PNG or PGM images? Obviously supposing the same image size.

Answer (score 2):

This question does not make sense. 
SIFT is an algorithm, it operates on raw pixel data in memory, not on files.
You would need some framework that loads image files into some data structure in memroy.

SIFT itself doesn't care if you load a jpeg or a pgm. It will never know where the pixels came from.

Having the same size (to 1 bit) for the same image in three different formats would be pretty impossible in my opinion. As PGM is uncompressed this would also mean that JPEG and PNG would have to be uncompressed to have roughly the same size. If you have no compression you have no losses. So there would be no difference in SIFT performance.

Comment: by size I mean width and height.

Comment: well then it would depend on the compression losses you have which you did not specify. if you have the same width and height you have the same number of pixels to process. hence speed should be the same, results will of course deteriorate with increasing information loss.